# add-ons/extension, how to program?

Tags: api, reflection, compilation, add-on

I want to know how to enable the developers to create add-ons for my application like chrome, firefox, blender and VS? 
I'm asking here about the concept how the made it?
 programmatically, what I need to provide in my application with to make this?
any references I may help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of options.

You can embed a scripting language (or an entire VM, like .NET or JVM) into your application, providing a decent API for all the internal functionality. If your application is built on top of such a VM already, chances are you don't need to do anything specific to enable an extensibility, just make sure your API is available and documented. Popular embedded scripting choices are Lua, Python, Guile and Tcl.

Alternatively, for a purely native code, you can provide your API as a separate dynamic linking library, and allow to load third party modules (linked to that library).

You can also make your application modular (split into separate processes), with the components talking to each other over a simple, text-based protocol via pipes or sockets. A very elaborate and powerful infrastructure is available for such an integration option, which is known as the "Unix way". In this case users will be able to choose any way of integrating their extensions with your core functionality.

Choose any, depending on a nature of your application.

Comment: any references I may help me?

Comment: My application is for web design.

Comment: @Amged, for anything more specific I'd need to know what is your platform and what kind of functionality you're ready to expose to the plugins. In a time being, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_way and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx